# JQuery getting object properties from GSON

Tags: jquery, gson

I have a HashMap of  this is getting written to JSON via GSON as below:

```
Map<Obj1, List<Obj2>> map = new HashMap<Obj1, List<Obj2>>();
// map populated
// 
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map));
```

I can see the data populated in JSON correctly when I do the following:

```
success: function(data) {                                   
                            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                                console.log(key);                                       
                            });
                        },
```

Console:

Obj1 [name=901098687, date=null]

Obj1 [name=901098682, date=12:30:12]

However, whenever I can't seem to access the properties of the object. I've tried several of the below and they either return undefined or throw an error:
console.log(key.name);

console.log(key.Obj1.name);

console.log(Obj1.name);

console.log(data['Obj1'].name);

I feel like there is something very easy I'm missing. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: That returns undefined. I didn't list all of the variations I tried, but it was quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using this jQuery code to render the JSON file:

```
var rows = ${reportRows};
var html = $.each(rows, function(key, value){

    $("#reportTable").append("<tr>");

    $.each(value, function (key, data) {
        $("#reportTable").append("<td>" + data + "</td>");
    });

    $("#reportTable").append("</tr>");

});
```

Where **${reportRows}** is the JSON generated string.